# Where's the logical error in the for loop

Tags: c#, for-loop, concatenation

```
public class Client
{
    public string nome;
}

Client j, h, m, n;
j = h = m = n = new Client();

Client[] c= new Client[]{j,h,m,n};
int[] n = new int[c.Length];

for (int i = 0; i < c.Length; ++i)
{
    n[i] =i;
    c[i].nome = "Client"+i;

}
```

In the output of `n = 0,1,2,3`;

but in the output of `c = Client4,Client4,Client4,Client4`

I'm not a freshman in programming, but I can't figure it out why it isn't concatenating each i value.
I can't explain to my self. there is `c[i]`, it should work.

Can anyone help with this?

Comment: `j = h = m = n = new Client();` assigns the same reference to all. It's not a shortcut for executing the same statement for every variable.

Comment: `j = h = m = n = new Client();` creates a single instance and assigns it to all 4 variables

Comment: Your code is almost complete, but you left out the crucial part. Also it is inconsistent, where is `[] c` ? Make it an [mcve]

Comment: As others have mentioned you create only a single object and reference it by 5 variables. Instead create five instances: `j = new Client(), h = new Client(), m = new Client() ...`. No each of those five instances has its own `nome`-property.

Comment: Your `Client` is a class => Is a reference type and you have 4 references but only 1 instance. Draw a picture.

Comment: My wife has a son. I have a son (the same child). If I shave the head of my wife's son, will my son's head also be shaved? Yes. That is what is happening here. You have two variables pointing to the same object (son).

Comment: Thanks @mjwills, nice example.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The code:

```
j = h = m = n = new Client();
```

creates the `j`, `h`, `m` and `n` references to a *single* new object.

Hence, the line `c[i].nome = "Client"+i;` will set the `nome` field of that single object, overwriting all the changes already done to it by previous iterations of the loop. In other words, what you have is:

```
 j ---+
      |    +-------------+
 h ---+--> | single item |
      |    +-------------+
 m ---+
      |
 n ---+
```

If you want *distinct* objects, you need to use something like:

```
j = new Client();
h = new Client();
m = new Client();
n = new Client();
```

That way, when you change one of the objects, it won't affect the others:

```
      +------+         +------+
j --> | item |   h --> | item |
      +------+         +------+
      +------+         +------+
m --> | item |   n --> | item |
      +------+         +------+
```

---

And, as an aside, if you're looking for a source-size-efficient way of doing this (as seems to be the case from your comments), you can just try getting rid of the middle men.

There's no need for those `j/h/m/n` temporary references and no *real* excuse for using single-character variable names anyway. Well, other than `i`, of course :-)

That would be something like::

```
Client[] clientArray = new Client[] {
    new Client(), new Client(), new Client(), new Client()
};
int[] numArray = new int[clientArray.Length];
for (int i = 0; i < clientArray.Length; ++i) {
    numArray[i] = i;
    clientArray[i].nome = "Client" + i;
}
```

Comment: The fact of they all being a single new object, makes them individually immutable?

Comment: @Belarmino what do you mean by that? Reference types aren't immutable. Your mutating one object, to which all variables point.

Comment: Yeah, I know that. 

I never my that kind of initialization x=y=z...

Now it makes more sense.

Comment: I was trying yo write less code, so I use this logic.

int a=4; int b,c,d;
b=c=d=a;

So they all would have 4.

But then I could change it later

Comment: Damn you with your ASCII art, I was just drawing that. Have an upvote.

Comment: @CodeCaster. *tremble* at my awesome graphical skills :-)

Comment: @BelarminoVicenzo your `int` example is different. `int` is a value type so each variable is it's own individual copy.  Though, int doesn't have any properties you can assign to so the comparison isn't exactly the same.

Comment: Yup, I know. I was so blind in shorten my code that I forgot it wouldn't work.